# Can every tag in html have id and class?

Tags: html, class, tags

I mean, can even `<b>` and `<em>` and `<strong>` have `id` and `class`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they all can. They're [global attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute).

> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on all
> HTML elements (even those not defined in this specification):
> ...
> class
> ...
> id
> ...